# UWP Restore vielmodel state when navigate back

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to save model (Player class) from my modelview(pvm object) and restore it when navigate back this  way:

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;//abre pasta do app
        StorageFile jsonFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("PlayerSaveState", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);//cria/substitui arquivo

        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(jsonFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(pvm.Player));
```

and

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {

        if (e.NavigationMode != NavigationMode.Back) { 
            if (e.Parameter is string)
            {
                pvm = new PlayerViewModel(e.Parameter as string); //defalt constructor
            }
            else
                pvm = new PlayerViewModel(e.Parameter as PlayerStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile jsonFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("PlayerSaveState");
            String json = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jsonFile);
            pvm = new PlayerViewModel(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Player>(json));
            DataContext = pvm;
        }
    }
```

PlayerViewModel(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json)); in this constructor I set the value of saved Model object, But it does not work, the view do not Bind the values.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if all of your  your properties in the viewmodel they implement INotifyPropertyChanged. and your class Player must implement this interface as well.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, the binding works ok, when you navigate forward to the page (i.e the `if` block of `OnNavigatedTo` is executed), but doesn't work when you navigate back (i.e. the `else` block is executed). This means that the issue is caused by something that is different between both blocks of code.

I suggest you take a closer look at the following:

1. You're only setting `DataContext` to `pvm` in the `else` block. In the `if` block you're only setting the value of `pvm` but not assigning to `DataContext`. Where exactly is `pvm` declared and how is it further used in the page? How is it related to `DataContext` at all?
2. Is `PlayerViewModel` constructed correctly in the second case? You are using different constructors in every call (passing `string` or `PlayerStatus` in the `if` block, but `Player` in the `else` block). Also make sure that the `Player` instance is deserialized as expected.

There's also a possibility of a race condition in the page. `OnNavigatedTo` is asynchronous and not awaitable, so other code in the page might be running when you're restoring the state from the file, but not when you're directly instantiating `PlayerViewModel` in the `if` block.

I hope this helps. Without seeing the rest of the page and the view model code, it's difficult to be more exact.